# iOS - how to get access to a variable from the container view and pass it back to the view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, didselectrowatindexpath, uicontainerview

I've a 'viewContoller' **VC1** and a container view in it with a table view controller embedded in **VC1**.

I've a variable called number which is adding up according to the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and deducting using `didDeselectRowAtIndexRowPath` since its a table.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    number += [[[self.sports objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"sportNumber"] intValue];
}

 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    number -= [[[self.sports objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"sportNumber"] intValue];
}
```

This "number" value belongs to the embedded table controller and I need to access it in **VC1**.

Additionally the "number" variable constantly changes according to it being selected or deselected and **VC1** needs to know when this happens so it has the most updated value.

I've been looking for a solution for days, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, do as below,

1) Go to interface builder and set name to your segue of UIContainerView embed (let's say '`abc`'). Later we are gonna access it from VC1(in step 4).

---

2) Define your `number` variable in VC1 header.

---

3) In table view controller header define a reference to your VC1 like this,

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) VC1 *VC;
```

---

4) In VC1 class, implement `prepareForSegue` and do as below,

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSString * segueName = segue.identifier;
    if ([segueName isEqualToString: @"abc"]) {
        TableViewController *tblVC = (TableViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
        tblVC.VC = self;
    }
}
```

5) Now in table view controller you can access your number variable like below,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (self.VC) {
        self.VC.number += [[[self.sports objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"sportNumber"] intValue];
  }   
}

 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (self.VC) {
    self.VC.number -= [[[self.sports objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"sportNumber"] intValue];
  }
}
```

Now you can access `number` variable from `VC1` since it is defined in `VC1` header. Remember this is just one way to achieve your requirement, There are several ways to handle this kind of situations. Such as, if you want you can do other way around too.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did define it as a global property but in the table view controller. So are you suggesting I need to subclass the table view controller and then move the didSelect and didDeselect methods to the viewcontroller instead of in the table view controller that way I can access it?

Comment: @Tony.C answer modified with the exact solution.

Comment: Hey Prasad thanks for the response. Everything works execept self.VC.number in the didselect method. It does not recognise the number variable.

And for this @property(nonatomic, retain) VC1 *VC; I replaced it with @property(nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *VC;

Comment: @Tony.C, You can't use UIViewController directly, Instead you should use your own 'viewcontroller' class which subclassed UIViewController, And inside your 'viewcontroller' you should define your number variable. Let me know if it's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, you have a tableView inside a VC and you want to be updated when a user didSelect/DidDeselect a row.

An alternative solution will be having a protocol implementation.

```
@protocol SpecialTableViewFunctionDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)didSelectSomethingUpdatedNumber:(NSNumber *)number;
- (void)didDeselectSomethingUpdatedNumber:(NSNumber *)number;
@end
```

This is of course assuming you subclassed tableView.

On your tableView subclass you can add the delegate for example:

```
@interface tableviewSubclass :UITableView
@property (nonatomic, weak)id<SpecialTableViewFunctionDelegate>delegate;
@end
```

then on your did select method you can do something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  number += [[[self.sports objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"sportNumber"] intValue];
  if(_delegate){
     if([_delegate respondsToSelector:(@selector(didSelectSomethingUpdatedNumber:)]){
        [_delegate didSelectSomethingUpdatedNumber:number];
     }
  }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   number -= [[[self.sports objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"sportNumber"] intValue];
   if(_delegate){
      if([_delegate respondsToSelector:(@selector(didDeselectSomethingUpdatedNumber:)]){
         [_delegate didDeselectSomethingUpdatedNumber:number];
     }
   }
  }
}
```

then on your VC you just have to assign the delegate to self.
     `tableViewInstance.delegate = self;`

Dont forget to include the delegate to the header `<SpecialTableViewFunctionDelegate>`

This way you'll be notified when there is a select/deselect of cell

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to clarify my question I have a container view inside the view controller which is embedded with a table view controller. The above methods belong to the table view and the variable "number" does get updated inside the table view with these methods.

However in my view controller that contains this table view (which is embedded from the container view) needs to use the number variable.

Your solution is assuming I am able to access the variable already which I can't. Hopefully I'm not misunderstanding. I did not subclass the table view.

Comment: @Tony.C actually you dont need to have access to it since you are just passing the number on the delegate to the vc. since you did not subclass the tableview then this approach will not be applicable. I suggest subclassing it and giving it a protocol as describe. this way you are not directly accessing the variable but passing it to the assigned delegate. I do hope I made a clear explanation about my suggested approach

Answer (score 0):

Sharing data between different classes can be done in various ways but the most cleaner way to do is to keep the shared data outside of all classes who are using/modifying this value by following the loosely coupled design.
One can think of a Singleton class but that will be kind a overuse if we have only one property (value) which is being shared.In this case we can have a class with one internal static variable and class methods (with + sign) to access it. Here is the code for the same:

```
.h file--->
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SharedData : NSObject

+(void)resetNumber;
+(void)incrementNumber;
+(void)decrementNumber;
+(int)getNumber;
@end]
```

.m File --->

```
#import "SharedData.h"

@implementation SharedData

static int number;

+(void)resetNumber {
    number = 0;
}

+(void)incrementNumber {
    number++;
}

+(void)decrementNumber {
    number--;
}

+(int)getNumber {
    return number;
}


@end
```

Here is the usage of the class
Use @class SharedData only to import it before @implementation

```
[SharedData incrementNumber]
```

Hope this might help you !!!!!